# Дохлый SSL-сертификат, который берется из ниоткуда

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, ssl, https

Собственно возникла подобная проблема при попытке установки сертификата на сайт. Домен от 2domains, DNS сервер был от jino.
И при попытке зайти по HTTPS все браузеры выдавали, что сертификат просрочен, выпущенный каким-то internet widgits pty ltd, хотя брал в совсем другом месте и в другую дату.

Потом оказалось, что даже если вообще завершить апач, или настроить его на 80 порт и отключить SSL (и перезагрузить!), и попытаться зайти по https:// то все равно так будет.

И подобную ерунду я замечаю и на других чужих сайтах, где HTTPS вроде как не поддерживается, но по https:// есть какой-то просроченный сертификат. Такое было на 3 сайтах из 5, на других 2 было либо timed out, либо refused.

Вопрос — откуда оно берется?

Особый акцент: от браузера (вернее, HTTP-клиента с SSL) и от провайдера клиента не зависит совершенно.

Comment: Если вы действительно выключили SSL и убедились, что на сервере 443 порт никем не занят и при этом https начинает устанавливать соединение и дает неверный сертификат, то тут только 2 варианта: либо вы обращаетесь не на ту машину, где меняете настройки апача, либо что то вклинивается в цепочку между отправкой запроса и приходом его на сервер. Это может быть какая нибудь прокси, включенная в вашем web-клиенте, отдельный софт на вашей машине, или трафик перехватывается где то по дороге от вас до сервера

Comment: @Mike на клиенте точно нет ничего, я же сказал. ВСЕ клиенты такое выдают, даже онлайн-сервисы. машина точно та. попробую даже IP сервера в dns-записях изменить позже.

Comment: «Другие чужие сайты» могут быть устроены совершенно по другому, так что нечего их сюда прплетать. Вы лучше про себя подробнее расскажите — какой сервер, какой апач, точно ли 443 отсутствует во всех конфиг-файлах апача и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Многие компании, предоставляющие услуги хостинга (от шаред до VDS) имеют собственные системы, упрощающие развёртывание серверов из образов виртуальных машин. Однажды делается образ системы, в которую ставятся все необходимые пакеты и потом развёртывание занимает в десятки раз меньше времени. Отсутствие ошибок, экономия на персонале, увеличение финансовых показателей компании.

Так вот достаточно часто видел ситуацию, когда один и тот же образ использовался более года, что приводит к тому, что SSL-сертификаты, зашитые в образ успевают заблаговременно протухнуть.

Это похоже как раз ваш случай.

Что и как там настроено внутри машины -- надо разбираться в каждом конкретном случае, а вы эту информацию не привели. Жаль.

Ну в первую очередь выясните, кто на вашей машине слушает 443 порт: если это не апач (в выключенном состоянии тот же сертификат продолжает показываться), то какой-нибудь nginx или что-то ещё похожее.

Дайте команду:

```
netstat -natp
```

И почитайте её вывод.

У вас же хостинг полноценный, с root'ом или всё же шаред с какой-нибудь самописной панелькой?